# Writing Dataframes to Different excel Sheets

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe, openpyxl

I am scraping some data on the web and writing it to about 6 dataframes. I then want to write each of these dataframes to a separate sheet in an Excel file. I have looked online and tried two different things and am unable to get the result I'm after. If I use the following code, it only writes the last dataframe to excel and everything else is overwritten:

```
book = "Sample.xlsx"
rb = openpyxl.load_workbook(book)
rb.create_sheet(pitches[x] + ' Data')
activeSheet = pitches[x] + ' Data'
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(book, engine='xlsxwriter')
combinedDF.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=activeSheet,  index=False)
writer.save()
```

If I use the following section of code, it creates each individual sheet, but no dataframe data is written to the excel file:

```
book = "Sample.xlsx"
rb = openpyxl.load_workbook(book)
rb.create_sheet(pitches[x] + ' Data')
activeSheet = pitches[x] + ' Data'
combinedDF.to_excel(book, sheet_name=activeSheet,  index=False)
rb.save(book)
```

Here is the full code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import pandas as pd
import openpyxl
book = "Baseball Savant Data.xlsx"
rb = openpyxl.load_workbook(book)
pitches = ['Fastball', '2 Seam Fastball', 'Cut Fastball', 'Split-Finger 
Fastball', 'Sinker', 'Slider', 'Changeup', 'Curveball']


beginningTime = time.time()
browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get('http://www.baseballsavant.com')
browser.maximize_window()
linkPage = browser.find_element_by_link_text('Statcast Search')
linkPage.click()
time.sleep(2)
myMinimumPitchCount = browser.find_element_by_xpath("""//*
[@id="min_pitches"]/option[@value='500']""").click()

myMinimumResultCount= browser.find_element_by_xpath("""//*
[@id="min_results"]/option[@value='50']""").click()

pitchCode = ['FF','FT','FC','FS','SI','SL','CH','CU']
time.sleep(2)
x = 0
y = 0


while x < len(pitchCode):
    if x == 0:
        current = ('chk_PT_' + pitchCode[x])
        pitchSelection = browser.find_element_by_class_name("mock-pulldown-
container")
        pitchSelection.click()
        currentPitch = browser.find_element_by_id(current).click()
        searchButton = browser.find_element_by_xpath("""//*
[@id="pfx_form"]/div[2]/div/input[1]""").click()
        time.sleep(3)

        while y < 2:
            if y == 0:
                currentURL = browser.current_url
                r = requests.get(currentURL)
                soup=BeautifulSoup(r.text, "html.parser")
                table_headers_data = soup.find("table", {"id" : 
"search_results"})
                statistics = soup.findAll("tr", {"class" : "search_row"})

                table_headers = [th.text.strip() for th in 
table_headers_data.findAll('th')[0:5]]
                data_rows = statistics[:]
                player_data = [[td.text.strip() for td in 
data_rows[i].findAll('td')[0:5]]
                    for i in range(len(data_rows))]

                dfPitchCount = pd.DataFrame(player_data, index=None, 
columns=table_headers)
                print('Y = ' + str(y))
                y+=1


            elif y != 0:
                wOBAAllowed = browser.find_element_by_xpath("""//*
[@id="sort_col"]/option[@value='woba']""").click()
                searchButton = browser.find_element_by_xpath("""//*
[@id="pfx_form"]/div[2]/div/input[1]""").click()
                time.sleep(2)
                currentURL = browser.current_url
                r = requests.get(currentURL)
                soup=BeautifulSoup(r.text, "html.parser")
                table_headers_data = soup.find("table", {"id" : 
"search_results"})
                statistics = soup.findAll("tr", {"class" : "search_row"})


                table_headers = [th.text.strip() for th in 
table_headers_data.findAll('th')[0:4]]

                data_rows = statistics[:]
                player_data = [[td.text.strip() for td in 
data_rows[i].findAll('td')[0:4]]
                   for i in range(len(data_rows))]

                dfwOBA = pd.DataFrame(player_data, index=None, 
columns=table_headers)
                combinedDF = pd.merge(dfPitchCount, dfwOBA, how='left', 
on="Player", sort=False, indicator = "True")
                print(rb.get_sheet_names())

                rb.create_sheet(pitches[x] + ' Data')
                activeSheet = pitches[x] + ' Data'
                writer = pd.ExcelWriter(book, engine='xlsxwriter')
                combinedDF.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=activeSheet, 
index=False )
                writer.save()
                pitchSort = browser.find_element_by_xpath("""//*
[@id="sort_col"]/option[@value='pitches']""").click()
                print('Y = ' + str(y))
                y+=1
                print('this is ' + str(x))
                x+=1


    elif x != 0:
        y=0
        print('y boogers = ' + str(y))
        pitchSelection = browser.find_element_by_class_name("mock-pulldown-
container")
        pitchSelection.click()
        time.sleep(5)
        current = ('chk_PT_' + pitchCode[x])
        previous = ('chk_PT_' + pitchCode[x-1])
        previousPitch = browser.find_element_by_id(previous)
        previousPitch.click()
        time.sleep(1)
        print(current)        
        pitchSelection.click()
        currentPitch = browser.find_element_by_id(current)
        currentPitch.click()
        time.sleep(1)
        print(previous)
        pitchSort = browser.find_element_by_xpath("""//*
[@id="sort_col"]/option[@value='pitches']""").click()
        searchButton = browser.find_element_by_xpath("""//*
[@id="pfx_form"]/div[2]/div/input[1]""").click()

        while y < 2:
            if y == 0:
                currentURL = browser.current_url
                r = requests.get(currentURL)
                soup=BeautifulSoup(r.text, "html.parser")
                table_headers_data = soup.find("table", {"id" : 
"search_results"})
                statistics = soup.findAll("tr", {"class" : "search_row"})

                table_headers = [th.text.strip() for th in 
table_headers_data.findAll('th')[0:5]]
                data_rows = statistics[:]
                player_data = [[td.text.strip() for td in 
data_rows[i].findAll('td')[0:5]]
                    for i in range(len(data_rows))]

                dfPitchCount = pd.DataFrame(player_data, index=None, 
columns=table_headers)

                y+=1

            elif y != 0:
                wOBAAllowed = browser.find_element_by_xpath("""//*
[@id="sort_col"]/option[@value='woba']""").click()
                searchButton = browser.find_element_by_xpath("""//*
[@id="pfx_form"]/div[2]/div/input[1]""").click()
                time.sleep(2)
                currentURL = browser.current_url
                r = requests.get(currentURL)
                soup=BeautifulSoup(r.text, "html.parser")
                table_headers_data = soup.find("table", {"id" : 
"search_results"})
                statistics = soup.findAll("tr", {"class" : "search_row"})


                table_headers = [th.text.strip() for th in 
table_headers_data.findAll('th')[0:4]]

                data_rows = statistics[:]
                player_data = [[td.text.strip() for td in 
data_rows[i].findAll('td')[0:4]]
                   for i in range(len(data_rows))]

                dfwOBA = pd.DataFrame(player_data, index=None, 
columns=table_headers)
                combinedDF = pd.merge(dfPitchCount, dfwOBA, how='left', 
on="Player", sort=False, indicator = "True")
                print(combinedDF)
                print(rb.get_sheet_names())

                rb.create_sheet(pitches[x] + ' Data')
                activeSheet = pitches[x] + ' Data'
                writer = pd.ExcelWriter(book, engine='xlsxwriter')

                combinedDF.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=activeSheet,  
index=False)
                writer.save()
                pitchSort = browser.find_element_by_xpath("""//*
[@id="sort_col"]/option[@value='pitches']""").click()

                y+=1

                x+=1
```

Comment: What is `x`?  Maybe a loop?

Comment: Yes, it is a loop - there is a bunch of other code but everything else seems fine. It also isn't written very efficiently yet so I plan to fix some of that but just need help figuring out why it is overwriting the sheets or why it isn't writing the data in the second code.

Comment: If you have a loop, you need to show the loop in your examples.

Comment: I can add all that, but again the code isn't very efficient and I don't necessarily think it is completely necessary. The loop is working fine. In the second example, it loops through and names each sheet as it should; however, the sheets are empty as the dataframe data isn't written to them. In the first example, the loop works correctly, but the final item in the loop is the only remaining sheet. Therefore, I am wondering how to use pandas and openpyxl to write each dataframe to a separate excel sheet.

Comment: No is asking for or even wants "*all that*"  Just enough to demonstrate the problem. You can learn [How to Ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example. That makes it easier for us to help you.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't trying to be difficult or anything, it was just a lot of code and formatting but I have edited it to include the full code.

Comment: Well that is certainly *"all that"*.  One reason we ask for an MCVE is just having the discipline to do this on your own will often allow you to solve the problem yourself.  But if you don't solve the problem and have boiled it down to an MCVE, then someone more knowledge than you who is trying to GIVE you their time, for free, to help, does not themselves need to boil it down.  Which takes time.  Which we are already giving away.

Comment: I'll work on that going forward. I've just been banging my head against my table for a week or so trying to figure out how to write pandas to excel without overwriting the previous data. Maybe it is best to write to a csv and copy it in to excel?

Answer (score 1):

It seems you missed the most important source: pandas documentation of `to_excel`: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html

So, put `writer = pd.ExcelWriter(book, engine='xlsxwriter')` and `writer.save()` out of the loop: the first before to start the `x` loop, and the second after it: you should open and save the excel file just once, not at every sheet write.

Comment: I did look at the documentation for to_excel but I guess I didn't figure it out. I'm still relatively new to python but I tried to research it. That makes sense though to put the writer outside of the loop - I will try it after work today and mark your answer as correct.                                              That seems to be so obvious in hindsight - I tried walking through my code to make sure it was doing everything I thought it should and I still missed that. Any tips/tricks on how you walk through your code to make sure it's truly doing what you intend it to?

Comment: The trick is to write readable code. Take time. Sometime I block myself few minutes, on thinking a good variable name. Readable code helps to find bugs. I have no idea what `x` and `y` mean in your code. Your `while` and `for.. range(len(..))` should possibly be written more pythonic. I smell a lot of C on your code. Experience helps: write and debug a lot of your code, read code from others (e.g. examples, blogs, but also real code in github)

Comment: My only experience is with VBA and that's limited as well so I am quite new to coding, with no experience in C. I know there is a lot of duplicate code so I plan to try to write a function for parts of it. I think I get caught trying to get a specific project done for myself and I'm so new that I just do what I know works or what I have found online. I guess the x and y don't necessarily mean anything, they are just the mechanism for looping if that makes sense? If you have time, could you give an example of writing the while and for loops more pythonic? Thanks so much for the feedback.

Answer (score 0):

The pandas documentation for [ExcelWriter](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.ExcelWriter.html) suggests that the "writer should be used as a context manager".

Here's an example of such usage to write multiple dataframe objects to an Excel file:

```py
import pandas as pd
dfList = [pd.DataFrame([[i + 1, i + 2, i + 3],['a', 'b', 'c']], columns=['col1', 'col2', 'col3']) for i in range(5)]
with pd.ExcelWriter('Sample.xlsx') as writer:
    for i, df in enumerate(dfList):
        df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=f'Sheet {i}', index=False)
```